# Adding one-off extra firings to a Quartz CronTrigger

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I was wondering how I might take a CronTrigger and add an extra one-off firing such that I can iterate over the firing times as I might with the getFileTimeAfter(Date) method

Say if I had a CronTrigger expressed by: "0 0 12 * * ?"

How might I add one additional firing as might be expressed by a SimpleTrigger with no repeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with `CronTrigger` itself. You can, however, associate as many different Triggers with a given `JobDetail` as you like.

You could simulate what you're trying to achieve by registering your `CronTrigger` plus a `SimpleTrigger`, call `getFireTimeAfter` on each trigger, and take the earlier value.

Annoyingly, `getFireTimeAfter` is present on both `CronTrigger` and `SimpleTrigger`, but isn't in the `Trigger` interface. That's the least of Quartz's API sins, mind you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... just thought I might be missing something obvious.
Quartz newb here, can you point me in the direction of any critiques of it?

Comment: Not really, because it's the only game in town. We just have to grin and bear it.

Comment: Actually, getFireTimeAfter(Date) is in the Trigger interface, at least from 1.6.x. Works too, I've used it. http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/api/org/quartz/Trigger.html#getFireTimeAfter(java.util.Date)

Comment: Ah, OK. I'm only familiar with 1.5